# vispy: two data sets on same plot with colors

Tags: python, point-clouds, vispy

I have two 3d numpy arrays, and am trying to plot them in two distinct colors via a vispy 3d scatter.

I am already familiar with how you set data via scatter on vispy:

scatter.set_data(data)

where data is in the form of a numpy array. However, I need to plot two different data sets with two distinct colors, and I feel like there is something very obvious I am missing here. I'm fine with treating the two point sets as one data set, but then how do you get two distinct colors for the point groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the scatter example from the vispy repo to do what you are asking.

### Result:

[image]

### Code:

```
# pylint: disable=no-member
""" scatter using MarkersVisual """

import numpy as np
import sys

from vispy import app, visuals, scene


# build your visuals, that's all
Scatter3D = scene.visuals.create_visual_node(visuals.MarkersVisual)

# The real-things : plot using scene
# build canvas
canvas = scene.SceneCanvas(keys='interactive', show=True)

# Add a ViewBox to let the user zoom/rotate
view = canvas.central_widget.add_view()
view.camera = 'turntable'
view.camera.fov = 45
view.camera.distance = 500

# data
n = 500
# generate 2 point clouds
cloud1 = np.random.rand(n, 3) * 100
cloud2 = np.random.rand(n, 3) * 100
# cloud1 -> orange
# cloud2 -> white
color1 = np.array([[1, 0.4, 0]] * n)
color2 = np.ones((n, 3))

# stack point clouds and colors
pos = np.vstack((cloud1, cloud2))
colors = np.vstack((color1, color2))


# plot ! note the parent parameter
p1 = Scatter3D(parent=view.scene)
p1.set_gl_state('translucent', blend=True, depth_test=True)
p1.set_data(pos, face_color=colors, symbol='o', size=10,
            edge_width=0.5, edge_color='blue')

# run
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.flags.interactive != 1:
        app.run()
```